# WMI Security issue

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, domain-controller, wmi

When I am trying to access WMI from a remote domain controller using WMIMGMT.MSC, I keep getting "Failed to connect to \(remote server) because 'Win32: Access is denied.'.  Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this?

I have tried many of the different howtos I found through google and none of them worked. I renamed the logs and repository folder under C:\system32\wbem and rebuilt the repository. After this didn't work, I went into the security tab under WMI Control and allowed 'Everyone' all rights. This did not fix the problem. I believe it has something to do with impersonation, but when I tried a few google searches for this, it brought up scripting and programming help.

I can access WMI locally on the remote computer with no issues

Comment: Something else to add. I can access WMI locally on the remote computer with no issues.

Comment: When you write "remote domain controller", are you talking about a domain controller in the same domain, or in a "remote" domain (one that doesn't trust your domain)

Comment: It belongs to the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a firewall issue. You can run `netsh firewall set service RemoteAdmin enable` to create the firewall exception for remote WMI access.

If the account that you're using is not an administrator on the target machine, you'll also need to configure some DCOM settings on the target machine, as outlined [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa393266.aspx).

Comment: If it was a DCOM issue, wouldn't it prevent me from viewing the event viewer and services remotely? I am able to remotely view the event viewer and services. Also, I do not have windows firewall enabled on the machine.